# jquery datatables sort in javascript nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

The [jquery datatables plugin](http://datatables.net) is able to enhance an already existing html-table and is able to read a special `data-order` tag for providing a different sorting value, as seen here:

```
        <tr>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td data-order="1303686000">Mon 25th Apr 11</td>
            <td data-order="320800">$320,800/y</td>
        </tr>
```

I am trying the same with a nested javascript object as source, like so

```
{
    "jobDescription":"System Architect",
    "startDate": {
        "display": "Mon 25th Apr 11",
        "sort": 1303686000
    },
    "salary": {
        "display": "$320,800/y",
        "sort": 320800
    }
},
```

Anyone who already implemented that?

Comment: Are you trying to sort the javascript object or are you trying to create an html table from the javascript object and then sort it ?

Comment: @RobinLeboeuf I think he is trying to use the datatables plugin to display and sort his object.

Comment: sorry for the confusion - as @Danny said, I try to use the automatic sorting function of the jquery datatable plugin.